# multiple foreign key ERD

Tags: mysql, erd

I having a question about same FK using in the schema. Here is the question

```
|=======================================|
|                 Book                  |
|=======================================|
| Book_ID (PK)| Cover_Paper | Page_Paper|
|-------------|-------------|-----------|

|====================================|
|                Paper               |
|====================================|
| Paper_ID (PK)| Paper_Type | weight |
|--------------|------------|--------|
```

Let say, I have different type of paper with different weight use to print cover and page.

So I need to plug the Paper_ID as FK into Book table. The problem is, it is wrong to have different column name as FK. If I change the table to the same column name it will be so weird.

```
|==========================================|
|                   Book                   |
|==========================================|
| Book_ID (PK)| Paper_ID(FK) | Paper_ID(FK)|
|-------------|--------------|-------------|
```

Any help on this problem??

Comment: And to determine the foreign keys, first determine the relationship between Book and Paper. Is it M-N, 1-1 (Who has total participation?), 1-M. Because no table should have two foreign key that is not composite and refering to the same table...

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong to have column names that differ from the domain name of the column. In fact, it is often necessary.

The alternative - having two columns with the same name - is bad. How would you know which column indicated cover paper and which page paper? By position? This ties the meaning of the content to the physical representation of the data. What happens if I select `Book_ID` and just one of the `Paper_ID` columns? One wouldn't know, without additional external information, what the data means. Rather, that additional information should be part of the representation, so that it's as self-descriptive as possible.

In relations where each role is filled by a unique domain, it's easy enough to just use the name of the domain as the name of the role without confusion. If a book consisted of a single type of paper, talking about *the book's paper* makes sense. Same for *a bicycle's seat* and *a person's nose*.

However, when a relation has more than one of the same kind of thing, we need to indicate each thing's role. Distinguishing `Cover_Paper` and `Page_Paper` like you did is the right way to do it. (It's too bad SQL DBMSs don't have separate role and domain names for each column, but I digress.)

You could call it `Cover_Paper_ID` and `Page_Paper_ID`, it's sort of an industry convention to attach ID to surrogate identifier columns though I think it reads better without. In other relations, it's often sufficient to write just the role without the domain - e.g. in a `Marriage` we might have columns for `Husband` and `Wife`, instead of writing `Husband_Person` and `Wife_Person`.

Both Edgar Codd (author of *A Relational Model of Data for Large Shared Data Banks*) and Peter Chen (author of *The Entity-Relationship Model - Toward a Unified View of Data*) discuss roles in their papers. I highly recommend studying both, especially since very few online resources ever mention the topic.